# Access to fetch at 'API URL' from origin 'LOCALHOST' has been blocked by CORS policy .net 6

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, cors, .net-6.0

im getting this error.

```
Access to fetch at 'API_URL' from origin 'LOCALHOST_OR_HEROKU_URL' has been blocked by CORS policy: 
Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: 
The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'.
```

i have followed the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?view=aspnetcore-6.0#middleware-order) to order my Middleware, and include whats necessary from this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-6.0#). Here is my Program.cs file.

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy(name: "CORSPolicy",
        policy =>
        {
            policy.AllowAnyOrigin();
            policy.AllowAnyMethod();
            policy.AllowAnyHeader();
        });

});


builder.Services.AddControllers();

builder.Services
    .AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddJwtBearer(options =>
    {
        options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
        {
            ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
            ValidateIssuer = false,
            ValidateAudience = false,
            ValidateLifetime = true,
        };
    });

// i have registered my services here

builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();

var app = builder.Build();


// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseRouting();
app.UseCors("CORSPolicy");

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllerRoute("default", "{controller=values}/{action=get}  /{id?}");
});


app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

but im still getting that error from client side, and i dont know what im doing wrong.. please any help is appreciated. With thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'.

Error message clear says what is wrong here.
This one requirement is well described in [MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) (*Requests with credentials* part).

> The server must not specify the "*" wildcard for the Access-Control-Allow-Origin response-header value, but must instead specify an explicit origin; for example: Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://example.com

> If a request includes a credential (most commonly a Cookie header) and the response includes an Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * header (that is, with the wildcard), the browser will block access to the response, and report a CORS error in the devtools console.

Credentialed requests are requests that contain any cookie data (`Cookie` header) or  any data in `Authorization` header.

So, highly likely solution would be replacing this line:

```
policy.AllowAnyOrigin();
```

by setting explicit origin allowed.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your client application calling the Web API has the correct url with https://scheme.

So localhost:6700/api should be called as https://localhost:6700/api.

Please check and confirm :)

Comment: thanks for your reply, 
yes.. its using  https:// scheme.